# Error al configurar una relación @ManyToOne con JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, join

Estoy armando un CRUD con **Spring Boot** y **JPA**.
Me surgió el problema a la hora de hacer el `join` desde **Spring Boot**. Antes de hacer la relación en el front veía todo sin problemas. La base de datos es **MySQL** y esta corriendo desde un **Docker**. Creo que tengo que configurar la relación `OneToMany` en `Distribuidor`, pero no logro que funcione.

Dejo el código de las clases domain,

```
@Entity
public class Distribuidor {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;
   private String nombre;

   @Column(name="sitio_web")
   private String sitioWeb;  

@Entity
@Table(name = "Videojuegos")
public class Videojuegos {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;
   private String nombre;
   private String descripcion;

   @Column(name="imagen_url")
   private String imagenUrl;

   @ManyToOne
   private Distribuidor distribuidor;
```

Comment: Creo que el problema lo encuentro en la base de datos, es decir, cuando ejecuto el proyecto este crea las tablas y las relaciones, deberia crearme una fk que conecte videojuegos a distribuidor y viceversa, pero solo me esta creando la de videojuegos

Answer (score 0):

Te faltaría indicar cuál es la columna por la que vas a hacer el join.
En este caso simplemente tendrías que agregar la anotación `@JoinColumn` en la clase `Videojuegos`, de esta forma:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private Distribuidor distribuidor;
```

`@JoinColumn` busca el campo marcado como id de la clase relacionada, en este caso `Distribuidor`. Entre las opciones se puede especificar el nombre de la *clave foránea*.

Comment: lo intente, pero me devuelve otro error, como que no puede llegar a la propiedad de nombre del distribuidor, (TENGO LOS GETTER Y SETTER)
EL1008E: Property or field 'distribuidor' cannot be found on object of type 'com.example.learning.videojuegos.domain.Videojuegos' - maybe not public or not valid?

Comment: ¿Los getters y setters son públicos? En general, y en particular en Videojuegos.

Comment: si son publicos

Comment: Estaría bueno que subas a la pregunta los fuentes completos de ambas clases y el volcado de pila.

Comment: me encantaria pero de todas las formas que lo intento, me dice que la pregunta contiene mas codigo que texto -_-

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi
tenia que agregar el nombre del campo con el que hacia el join
Gracias

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="distribuidor_id")
    private Distribuidor distribuidor;
```